# can a deliberative body "resolve on" a matter?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I have been seeing phrases "The board of directors resolved on the budget." but have never heard, and in dictionaries have not found, a combination of "resolve" with preposition "on" to refer to the topic that a body must make a decision on.

The OED says to resolve in this sense generally takes an object clause, such as "The Committee resolved that it accepts the chairman's proposal." or "The shareholders resolved to go forward with the takeover bid." But when the actual tenor of the decision is not stated, only the topic on which a resolution must be passed, is it correct to use "resolve on"?

Comment: It's an old usage. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resolve+to%2Cresolve+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresolve%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresolve%20on%3B%2Cc0) will give you some examples.

Comment: Can you link the source of the sentence or add a few more sentences before and after that sentence? The sentence is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Rathony - "resolve on" is idiomatic.

Comment: @JOSH I have reviewed thousands of "resolution of board of directors". I have never seen "resolve on" used. That's what I mean by not idiomatic.

Comment: @Rathony - The expression does exist and has a different meaning from "resolve". It is idiomatic, formal and I have personally seen it used. I don't see the problem with this question. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resolve+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresolve%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JOSH Without surrounding sentences or context, it's not easy to tell. That's why I requested the OP include the source and more sentences.

Comment: @Rathony  - the board " took a final decision on the budget" that's the meaning. What the decision is about is not our concern.

Comment: @JOSH In that sense, you can just use "approve". To resolve in a board meeting means (1) they hear and consider a proposal, (2) they are asked to vote and (3) they approve it. As the OP mentions, it usually takes a complementary that clause after "on a date". Again, we don't know without any surrounding context. That's why this kind of question always should have the source of the sentence and more sentences. We don't even know where this sentence was used.

Comment: @Rathony - it is simpler than that, please have a look at my answer. The usage is quite old but still present. Please see Ngram above. I know you just want to CV this question. Just go ahead and do it. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a formal expression used in business/legal contexts that means "decide in favour of":

***[Resolve on](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-spanish/resolve_on)*** (resolve upon):

(Phrasal verb - formal)

> - the committee resolved on a subsidy for the group —

(ODO)

***[Resolve on:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=resolve)***

> - Meaning "determine, decide upon" is from 1520s, hence "pass a resolution".

(Etymonline)